# Data visualization of average and standard deviation over a small time series

Tags: r, time-series, data-visualization, many-categories

I am trying to find the best way to visualize the following data:

I have values for 3 different times/dates, each time/date has the same 20 species. For each species I have the average height and standard deviation (that was obtained from n observations). I don't have the observations from where the average and standard deviation was obtained.

This is how the data looks like. Species are numerated from 1 to 20.

```
t1 = cbind(seq(1,20,1),runif(20,0.5,5.0),runif(20,0,1.0))
t2 = cbind(seq(1,20,1),runif(20,0.9,6.0),runif(20,0.2,1.5))
t3 = cbind(seq(1,20,1),runif(20,0.1,8.5),runif(20,0.4,1.0))
```

Can anyone give any advice on what would be the best plot/graphic to use? I want to show the evolution of the average and standard deviation in time, however I don't want to do a line plot, and for a heat map I have a small dataset.

Comment: What's the objection to line plots?

Comment: all the data into one plot using lines will not give much info. by lines i refer to something like the first example given by @Penguin_Knight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not a line plot? A line plot seems pretty fitting if you'd like to show general trends in mean and SD provided individual specie is not the focal point.

---

Anyway, here is an alternative, which strictly speaking is still a line plot but time is not one of the axes. It is also good for discussing individual species. x-axis is your variable 1 (I guessed that's mean), y-axis is the variable 2 (SD).

[image]

---

And yes, heat map maybe too much, but I think it's worth a try to show 3D kernel density if you can provide the actual data as well. Codes are taken from [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31726/scatterplot-with-contour-heat-overlay).

[image]

---

Another possibility is to make three plots:

1. t1 SD vs. mean, use black symbol
2. t1 SD vs. mean, but this time the symbol turned to light grey; overlay t2 SD vs. mean, use black symbol. Connect each species pair with an arrow.
3. t2 SD vs. mean, but this time the symbol turned to light grey; overlay t3 SD vs. mean, use symbol. Connect each species pair with an arrow.

Answer (score 10):

You mean you don't want a line plot like this? :)

[image]

Time is a natural for the X axis and line plots. Here's a better view using a small multiples approach.

[image]

Sometimes it helps to order the panels by something analytical. Here's an example ordered by average std:

[image]

With so many category levels (20), another technique is to cluster similar levels and overlay those together. Here's an example with 4 clusters. (Not bothering with obvious but addressable deficiencies in coloring and labeling.)

[image]