# Fit circle of fixed diameter over most dense area of scatterplot

Tags: scatterplot

I am looking for a function that would help make a circle (of fixed diameter) over the most data points (highest density) on a two-dimensional scatter plot. I was hoping someone would at least point me in the direction I should be looking. I'm willing to do my own math. I was going to utilize this for a computer program.

Comment: This is unclear. Are you asking for code (in what language)? Note that asking for code / functions is off topic here.

Comment: I was expecting math function. I will try to implement it in code myself :)

Comment: You just want the formula for a circle?

Comment: I dont know. im not looking for piR^2 or 2piR though xD

Comment: It sounds like you are interested in a density contour plot or similar (see [e.g. this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31726/scatterplot-with-contour-heat-overlay)) but how do you know that the contours should form perfect circles? I think more information is needed here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume you have points ${\bf p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_k}\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Then your problem can of finding the $r$-diameter sphere containing the most points can be formulated as a mixed integer quadratically constrained program (MIQCP), with ${\bf x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ as the center of the sphere and ${\bf y}\in\{0, 1\}^k$ defining whether each point is within $r$ distance of the center:

$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\max & \sum_{i=1}^k y_i \\
\mathrm{subject~to} & \sum_{j=1}^n (x_j - p_{ij})^2~\leq~r^2+M(1-y_i)~~\forall~i \\
& y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_k~~\in~~\{0, 1\}
\end{array}
$$

Here, $M$ is an appropriately large constant. This can be formulated and solved by MIQCP-solving software, such as [BARON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BARON), [Couenne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Couenne), or [GAMS](https://www.gams.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fgams.doc%2Fuserguides%2Fmccarl%2Fmixed_integer_quadratically_constrained_program_%28miqcp%29.htm).

MIQCPs are difficult to solve, and the problem would be a good deal simpler to solve if you instead wanted to find the point that has [Manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) (aka 1-norm distance) of no more than $r$ from as many points as possible. This problem can be formulated as a mixed integer linear programming problem (MILP):

$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\max & \sum_{i=1}^k y_i \\
\mathrm{subject~to} & \sum_{j=1}^n z_{ij}~\leq~r+M(1-y_i)~~\forall~i \\
& z_{ij}~\geq~x_j - p_{ij}~~\forall~i,~j \\
& z_{ij}~\geq~p_{ij} - x_j~~\forall~i,~j \\
& y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_k~~\in~~\{0, 1\}
\end{array}
$$

MILPs can be solved with many different solvers, including both open-source and commercial options (commercial options will be needed for large problem instances). For instance, here is an implementation using the `lpSolve` package in R, using 25 randomly generated points and (1-norm) distance 1:

```
library(lpSolve)
# P is a k x n matrix
get.center <- function(P, r) {
  n <- ncol(P)
  k <- nrow(P)
  ij <- apply(expand.grid(i=1:k, j=1:n), 1, paste, collapse=" ")
  vars <- rbind(data.frame(type="xp", i=NA, j=1:n),
                data.frame(type="xn", i=NA, j=1:n),
                data.frame(type="y", i=1:k, j=NA),
                data.frame(type="z", i=rep(1:k, each=n), j=rep(1:n, k)))
  ij <- vars[vars$type == "z",c("i", "j")]
  M <- sum(apply(P, 2, max)) - sum(apply(P, 2, min))
  mod <- lp(direction="max",
            objective.in=(vars$type == "y")*1,
            const.mat=rbind(t(sapply(1:k, function(i) {
              (vars$type == "z" & vars$i == i) +
                M*(vars$type == "y" & vars$i == i)
            })),
            t(apply(ij, 1, function(idx) {
              (vars$type == "z" & vars$i == idx[1] & vars$j == idx[2]) -
                (vars$type == "xp" & vars$j == idx[2]) +
                (vars$type == "xn" & vars$j == idx[2])
            })),
            t(apply(ij, 1, function(idx) {
              (vars$type == "z" & vars$i == idx[1] & vars$j == idx[2]) +
                (vars$type == "xp" & vars$j == idx[2]) -
                (vars$type == "xn" & vars$j == idx[2])
            }))),
            const.dir=rep(c("<=", ">="), c(k, 2*n*k)),
            const.rhs=c(rep(r+M, k), -as.vector(t(P)), as.vector(t(P))),
            binary.vec=which(vars$type == "y"))
  mod$solution[vars$type == "xp"] - mod$solution[vars$type == "xn"]
}

set.seed(144)
P <- matrix(rnorm(50), nrow=25)
ctr <- get.center(P, 1)
plot(P, pch=16, col=ifelse(abs(P[,1]-ctr[1]) + abs(P[,2]-ctr[2]) <= 1.00001, "red", "black"))
points(ctr[1], ctr[2], pch=3, col="red")
```

The red points are the points within 1-norm distance 1, and the plus is the selected center:

[image]

Comment: thank you for your response kind sir. This actually might be what i need i just need to study your response for some time xD brb